# MASM x86 return a Byte array from proc

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

Is there a way to return a byte array from x86 ASM on MASM DLL into a C# code?

In my ASM proc the array is changed, and I want to use it on my C# code.

Comment: So you actually want to pass a Byte array by reference, not return a new one?

Comment: I could return a new one. They are both initialized in my proc
`calculateArray proc USES eax ebx ecx edx esi edi, lengthArray:DWORD, newLength: DWORD, tablica: PTR BYTE, tablicaDruga: PTR BYTE`

I  make changes from tablica to tablicaDruga, and I want to return it to C#.
`readyArray = MD5AsmDll.calculateArray(length, newLength, checksum, readyArray);`

Comment: @PeterCordes also the readyArray is empty in the beginning, its filled with elements during the calculateArray procedure

Comment: Does it need to be a function parameter in the first place?  Shouldn't it either be the return value *or* a pass-by-reference parameter, but not both?

Comment: It could be, but then I'd have to init it as LOCAL inside a proc, yes?

Comment: I don't use MASM.  But yes, you'd just reserve space for it like a local variable, I guess.  The hard part is going to be allocating the memory for it so that C# can use.  I'd imagine it'd be *much* easier to create it in C#, and allocate the required space before calling your asm function.  You might not be able to avoid having C# waste time zeroing it or something, though, instead of passing a pointer to the uninitialized space.

Comment: The array is initialized in C#. `byte[] readyArray = new byte[length + 64];`, where lenght is the size of the copied array, i also add few things. Right now when I've changed the proc to use the array as local, the function returns: `'System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException' occurred in GUI.exe

Additional information: Cannot organize "return value"`